# How to include time with Exception.printStackTrace();?

Tags: java, exception

I am writing all my exception log in a text file.

For example

```
pw= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("EXCEPTION.txt", true));

try
{ 
    do something!! 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(pw);pw.flush();
}
```

However, it is very hard to get the read the EXCEPTION.txt file when there are multiple exceptions. I think it would be better to include time in front of each exception.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply add the current date just before appending your stacktrace to the file. Also, you can format the date and write it.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    pw.write(new Date().toString()); // Adding the date
    pw.write(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())); // Formatted date
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    pw.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String timeNow = dateFormat.format(date); // pretty date
pw.write(timeNow + " " + e.getMessage()); // date concatenated with exception message
```